# How to Round Out the Corners of a Rectangular Button on .axml (Visual Studios 2019, Xamarin Forms)

Tags: rounded-corners

I am newer to coding but, usually, when I have a question it is answered by a quick google search or video explaining my issue. The title is basically the question but I will elaborate: How do you round out the corners of a rectangular button in .axml? I have tried making a drawable folder with specific corner parameters set and applying that to the button background but it doesn't change the button in any way. I know that in .xaml you can simply use the CornerRadius tag but that isn't defined in .axml. Sorry if I am not being specific enough with my issue, like I said, I am new, but would be willing to elaborate further if need be.
Thank you all:)